# Sitecore JSS error when creating quick start app with Vue template

Tags: jss

I'm trying to create a disconnected JSS vue app using the quick start guide, by running the following commands:

```
npm install -g @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli
jss create jss-app-vue vue
cd jss-app-vue
jss start
```

When I run the `jss start` command I get the following error:

```
Watching for changes to component factory sources in src/components...
INFO  Starting development server...
Enabling Babel 7 transpilation for the manifest...
ReferenceError: Unknown option: .caller. Check out 
http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.
at buildUnknownError (E:\Projects\jss-app-vue\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:113:11)
at Object.keys.forEach.key (E:\Projects\jss-app-vue\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:99:57)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at validate (E:\Projects\jss-app-vue\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\validation\options.js:69:21)
at loadPrivatePartialConfig (E:\Projects\jss-app-vue\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\partial.js:38:50)
at loadFullConfig (E:\Projects\jss-app-vue\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:43:39)
at loadOptions (E:\Projects\jss-app-vue\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\index.js:28:36)
at OptionManager.init (E:\Projects\jss-app-vue\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\index.js:34:12)
at compile (E:\Projects\jss-app-vue\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\node.js:61:42)
at compileHook (E:\Projects\jss-app-vue\node_modules\@babel\register\lib\node.js:102:12)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! jss-app-vue@9.0.6 start:proxy: `node scripts/disconnected-mode-proxy.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the jss-app-vue@9.0.6 start:proxy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It appears there's an issue running the `start:proxy` command.

NOTE: This only appears to affect the vue template. The issue doesn't occur if I create an app using the react template.

Are there any additional steps required to setup an app with the vue template?

For info I'm running node v8.11.3 and npm v5.6.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to a breaking change in one of the Vue sample's dependencies.

If you don't have `yarn` installed, the `jss create` command will use `npm install` when installing the sample (and dependencies). Unfortunately, using `npm install` does not respect the `yarn.lock` file in the Vue sample. Therefore, the dependencies for the Vue sample aren't guaranteed to be the correct version because `npm` will follow the version ranges from `package.json`.

This is already fixed for the JSS GA release, where we've switched all the samples to use `npm` instead of `yarn`.

In the interim, the easiest way to fix this would be to install `yarn` https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install.
Then run the `jss create jss-app-vue vue` command again.

Comment: Specifically on this error, setting the babel devDependency in your `package.json` to `"@babel/register": "7.0.0-beta.47",` should resolve this (after another npm install). You may also need to remove the `^` in front of other vue dependencies to specify the version is fixed there too.

Comment: Switching to yarn fixed the issue. I was unable to resolve making the changes to the package.json as suggested above. Thanks anyway! This gives us enough to begin PoCing.